# store image into a folder and its path into a database using spring rest controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Actually I have a criteria where I have to upload a product image into a folder and image name, image path , productname and producttype into mongoDb. I have successfully done uploading image into a particular folder from one endpoint(/uploadFile) by passing MultiPartFile as @RequestParam. I have written another enpoint to upload product details. but I am unable to get image name and image path into this endpoint(/uploadPath). Anyone there come across this situation please let me know

i got code from  https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/ to upload file now. I created a model class Image like

[Image Model Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEGww.png)

and service class as

[ImageService Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK4LF.png) 
and endpoint in rest controller like

[FileController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LY4A.png)

Actually I need Image name in folder and database to be same is it possible? how can I achieve this?
how do I map filename in folder to filename stored in database. How do I update filename using PUT

Comment: Share what have you done so far and error you get with us please

Comment: Share code for details

Comment: Can you explain or give me more details ?

Comment: refer the question I have added screen shots of my code.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the image, it is the content which is uploaded. Either you can take name of the file from FileUploader itself or you can name it whatever you want at the server. When image reaches to server, things are in your hand including the name you want it to have.

Comment: How can I access filename in one method from another method. How can I relate that Image uploaded to image details uploaded. I mean we have one endpoint for image upload and and another endpoint for image details. how can these two be related.

Comment: Siva, if you may have two tables as image and imageDetails connected by foreign key. While taking image details, you may pass the image key for which you are going to read the details.

Comment: Thanks for your response as I am using MongoDb i cant connect them as tables and. I am storing image into a folder not into a table. https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/ refer this link. I use this code to store images into server. I created image model with image details and image service for storing the details into db. In controller I created a method(uploadPath). My doubt is how to get file name from another method(uploadFile) .  Can I use stream.map to get file name and how?